# How to locate Automation Ids (winium automation) in Chrome legacy window of a desktop application

Tags: winium, ui-spy

I'm trying to automate an application that can be hosted on web browsers (Edge,chrome,firefox) and on desktop (windows 10) as well. For browser application I have used selenium tool for automation. In case of desktop application I'm trying to use Winium which works based on detection of object via automation Ids or names.

In my application that is hosted on desktop, the entire window gets displayed as "Chrome Legacy Window", thereby there is no automation Ids or names getting displayed for the application.
In such a situation I cannot proceed with automation.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You Could Try using Xpath locators as follows.

**driver.find_elements_by_xpath("*[starts-with(@Name, 'Element_')]")**

For more details refer [this](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/issues/111#issuecomment-235255628) and [this](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/wiki/Finding-Elements).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Akilan. Please look in to this for the actual problem - [here] [https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/issues/258]. UISpy tool itself displays that entire native desktop app page as "chrome legacy window". In that case even if i could locate the parent page based on Xpath locator, any idea how i could locate the child objects? Any help would be really appreciated.